# Spring PropertySource returns null

Tags: java, spring

Hello i'm currently going through getting values on `.properties` files. i have encountered a problem. I am using Spring Boot. See my sample source below;

**Browser.java**

```
@Controller
public class Browser {

    @Autowired
    private BrowserConfiguration conf;

    public Browser(){
        System.out.println("I am initializing...");
        System.out.println("Reading configuration files..."+conf);
        System.out.println("Starting selected browser...");
        System.out.println("Waiting for command execution...");
    }

}
```

**BrowserConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:./properties/test-config.properties")
public class BrowserConfiguration {

    @Value( "${browser.target}" )
    private String browser;

    public String getBrowser() {
        return browser;
    }

    public void setBrowser(String browser) {
        this.browser = browser;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Target Browser: "+getBrowser();
    }

}
```

**Demo1Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner  {

    @Autowired
    private Browser browser;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Mode.OFF);
        app.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        browser.runTest("test1");
    }
}
```

**test-config.properties**

```
browser.target=ie
```

**Console Logs**

```
2017-04-29 23:51:10.537  INFO 6912 --- [           main] com.example.Demo1Application             : Starting Demo1Application on Mikram-PC with PID 6912 (C:\Users\Mikram\sts-workspace\demo-1\target\classes started by Mikram in C:\Users\Mikram\sts-workspace\demo-1)
2017-04-29 23:51:10.540  INFO 6912 --- [           main] com.example.Demo1Application             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-04-29 23:51:10.576  INFO 6912 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@67b467e9: startup date [Sat Apr 29 23:51:10 SGT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
I am initializing...
Reading configuration files...null
Starting selected browser...
Waiting for command execution...
2017-04-29 23:51:11.051  INFO 6912 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
I am search now!
2017-04-29 23:51:11.062  INFO 6912 --- [           main] com.example.Demo1Application             : Started Demo1Application in 0.722 seconds (JVM running for 1.02)
2017-04-29 23:51:11.063  INFO 6912 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@67b467e9: startup date [Sat Apr 29 23:51:10 SGT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-29 23:51:11.064  INFO 6912 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

**Problem:**

I can't seem to connect the BrowserConfiguration inside Browser class. Did i miss something? please do point me to the right direction. im am at a lost right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using field injection, but access the variable inside the constructor. Because the constructor is called when the object is created Spring didn't have a chance yet to set the variable. In this case you have to use constructor based injection:

```
@Autowired
public Browser(BrowserConfiguration conf) {
    this.conf = conf;

    //Use the variable here
}
```

Comment: hmm this was spot on, but i didn't get your explanation.. why didn't it get automatically set when Browser bean is created?

Comment: When using `@Autowired` on fields Spring creates the object and then assigns the beans to them using Reflection. This is done **after** the object has been created. Since the constructor is actually part of the initialization of an object Spring can't inject fields yet. When annotating a constructor with `@Autowired` Spring calls the constructor with the correct beans as parameters, thus making them available during initialization

Comment: ohh i see is this something to do with it (BrowserConfiguration) an inner bean of Browser?

Comment: It's simply because of the way field injection works. To make it simple: Spring creates the Object(Browser in this case) using `new Browser()` and then sets the fields that are annotated with `@Autowired`, in this case: `browser.conf = new BrowserConfiguration();`. This is a very simple explanation, but should give you an idea how it works and how you can use it(field injection that is).